# my ubuntu terminal has changed, something amiss?

Tags: git, terminal

I can't even properly form it into a question, or even if its a problem. As a result of something (possible me, possible an update?). my terminal now looks like

```
drew@think$  cd drewPlay
~/drewPlay
drew@think$ (git::master)
```

before the ~/path didn't display and neither did (git::master). i'm curious what I have done to make this happen and probable how I need to fix what ever mistake this is highlighting.

Comment: a fair amount of things, i should keep better track of what i'm downloading.

Comment: For the problem with  `cd` look for `alias cd="..."`, and the `git::master` will likely be caused by some sort of bash autocompletion plugin.

Comment: Question is probably better suited for superuser.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your `.bashrc` file for the `PS1` variable - I bet it includes the `__git_ps1` helper and begins with `\w` followed by a newline - something like:

```
PS1='\w\n\u@\h\$$(__git_ps1 " (git::%s)") '
```

... would produce the prompt you're seeing.  If that were the case, you could put it back to something more conventional by changing it to:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

... but `__git_ps1` is pretty great :)